# Possessive and plural: usage of 们 and 的

Tags: grammar

This is a very basic question about a simple topic that is not really clear to me (curiously, my book doesn't address it, or, more probably, I don't get it).

There are rules to:

- to pluralize personal pronouns: just add "们" (e.g.: 我 [I] -> 我们 [we])
- to make possessive adjective from personal pronouns: just add "的" (e.g.: 我 [I] -> 我的 [my])

Can these rules be combined to make possessive adjective for plural pronouns (e.g.: 我 [I] -> 我们的 [our])?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes. 我们的=our, 他们的=their, 你们的=your, etc.

Comment: it can also be used as : 我们的=ours, 他们的=theirs, 你们的=yours,

Comment: 咱、咱们，您们（www： 过去不提倡用“您们”，如今在语言的实际运用中，说得比较多了）

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to Stan (see first comment in the question) and sotondolphin (see other answer), the answer is: Yes.
So:

```
我们的 -> our
你们的 -> your
他们的 -> their
她们的 -> their
它们的 -> their
```

Answer (score 2):

same rule applys for animal pronouns 它

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the suffix *de* 的 can make any noun (including pronouns) possessive. It has other uses, too, but the possessive is one important case.